# Pretty Palintiples

Tags: code-golf, number, sequence, number-theory, palindrome

Imagine you have a positive integer number \$n\$. Let \$m\$ be the number obtained by reversing \$n\$'s digits. If \$m\$ is a *whole* multiple of \$n\$, then \$n\$ is said to be a **reverse divisible number**. If neither are a **palindrome**, \$m\$ is called a **palintiple**.

For example, \$1089 \cdot 9 = 9801\$, so \$9801\$ is a **palintiple** because it is a whole multiple of its reversal, \$1089\$. Another example of a palintiple is \$8712\$, because \$2178 \cdot 4 = 8712\$.

It's easy to see that all **palindrome** numbers are reverse divisible, e.g. \$171 \cdot 1 = 171\$, so we're not interested in those, and we do not call them palintiples.

### Input

Your input is an integer \$x\$. You may assume \$x > 0\$.

### Output

Your task is to print out the first \$x\$ **palintiple** numbers. You can format your output however you like as long as every element is clearly separated.

### Test Cases

```
Input      Output
x = 1      8712
x = 3      8712, 9801, 87912
x = 7      8712, 9801, 87912, 98901, 879912, 989901, 8799912
```

### Rules

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest number of bytes wins.

Comment: Can we use other [standard sequence output formats](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/sequence/info)?

Comment: what happens to multiples of 10? 02 divides 20 and is not a palindrome?

Comment: @pajonk You can

Comment: @pacman256 Those are discarded. Any unnecessary 0s added to the left are avoided, so 02 is the same as 2. (otherwise 2 would somehow be a palindrome with itself or 20)

Comment: A better example would be 87120 which has 2718 as a divisor and neither are palindromes. It is probably best to state no `m` ending in a zero upfront (or you could word it as there must be a proper divisor of `m` that when reversed is `m`, since that cant _add_ zeros).

Comment: *Starts to wonder* is this all, and only those positive integers of the form of either `87[9]+12` and `98[9]+01`?

Comment: @JonathanAllan The patterns are probably a bit more complicated. For instance, `87128712` and `98019801` are palintiple numbers. Or does `[9]+` in your definition mean _digits whose sum reduces to 9_?

Comment: @Arnauld, no it was just nines, didn't see those ones, very interesting!

Comment: @JonathanAllan There are various patterns, for instance the number of palintiples for a given number of digits is twice the Fibonacci of the decremented (floored) half length.

Comment: This is [OEIS A031877](https://oeis.org/A031877).

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 61 bytes

```python
m=9
while 1:
 m+=1;r=int(`m`[::-1])
 if m in(4*r,9*r):print m
```

A full program that prints indefinitely.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9fWkqs8IzMnVcHQikshV9vW0LrINjOvRCMhNyHaykrXMFaTSyEzTSFXITNPw0SrSMdSq0jTqqAIqEQh9/9/AA)**

Why only multiples of four and nine? See the [OEIS page](https://oeis.org/A031877) and [this linked reference](https://djm.cc/rpa-output/arithmetic/digits/palintiples.s) by Dan Hoey.

---

If floating point errors are acceptable then (thanks to [l4m2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76323/l4m2))...

#### Python 3 57 bytes

```python
m=9
while 1:m+=1;int(str(m)[::-1])in(m/4,m/9)and print(m)
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/5fUJSZVxKfX5SZnpmXmKNgqwAW4AKTtjmJuUkpiQplVqiqNMp0FNJySoszbEOKSlM1/@faWnKVZ2TmpCoYWuVq2xpaAxVrFJcUaeRqRltZ6RrGambmaeTqm@jk6ltqJualQOwAyv7/DwA)** (The header just forces TIO to flush to stdout after each print, since it seems not to flush after the 60-second timeout.)

Comment: Why only 4 and 9 possible?

Comment: see, from OEIS.

Comment: Why [this](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P9fWkqs8IzMnVSHXxjDV1CpX29bQOjOvRKO4pEgjVzPaykrXMFYzM08jV99EJ1ffUjMxL0WhoAikIlfz/38A) work but removing end condition it doesn't?

Comment: Seems TIO isn't flushing - [TIO](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/5fUJSZVxKfX5SZnpmXmKNgqwAW4AKTtjmJuUkpiQplVqiqNMp0FNJySoszbEOKSlM1/@faWnKVZ2TmpCoYWuVq2xpaAxVrFJcUaeRqRltZ6RrGambmaeTqm@jk6ltqJualQOwAyv7/DwA). I'm not sure that the (eventual) floating point errors from the divisions would be acceptable however.

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 61 bytes

A full program that prints the sequence indefinitely.

```javascript
for(n=0;;n%r|r/n||print(n))r=[...++n+""].sort(_=>n%10).join``
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFBCoAgEAXQuwSCIk22C8QuEpESBLr4yiiuvLu9l0IP9eVY2tqPOb/MEs5YC8GDN4xROKJJKMXuIiKtoZflppq5ycedELtRlHKE93P@)

#### Commented

```javascript
for(              // main loop:
  n = 0;          //   start with n = 0
  ;               //   loop forever
  n % r           //   do nothing if r is not a divisor of n
  | r / n         //   or r = n
  || print(n)     //   otherwise, print n
)                 //
  r =             //   compute r:
    [...++n + ""] //     increment n and turn it into a list of digits
    .sort(_ =>    //     reverse this list if and only if ...
      n % 10      //     ... n is not a multiple of 10
    ).join``      //     join back to a string
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ÆḌDUḌ€ċµ#
```

A full program that accepts a positive integer, \$x\$, from stdin and prints a Jelly representation of the first \$x\$ *palintiples*.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9w28MdPS6hQOJR05oj3Ye2Kv//bwIA)** - N.B. it's very slow due to checking all proper divisors.

#### How?

```
ÆḌDUḌ€ċµ# - Main Link: no arguments
       µ# - start with m=0 and count up, collecting the first {stdin} m for which:
ÆḌ        -   {m}'s proper divisors (excludes m itself, catering for 
                                     the no-palindrome requirement)
  D       -   to decimal (vectorises) 
   U      -   reverse each
    Ḍ€    -   convert each from decimal (each as vectorised form would take
                                         [] to 0 giving a false positive of m=0)
      ċ   -   count occurrences of {m}
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 136 bytes

```hs
r 0 a=a
r n a=r(quot n 10)(a*10+mod n 10)
g n a|n<1=[]|mod a 10<1||r a 0==r(r a 0)0||mod a(r a 0)>0=g n(a+1)|1>0=a:g(n-1)(a+1)
f n=g n 1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYsxDsIwDEX3nMJjQoVkDyyo5iKIwRK0VLQupGXz3YPTMvm/9/2fsrwe41hKBgRhCRnUb46f77x6JExRDoTNNN93DH39MG2JrzerWly3ZJY9Ift2Cwltb/94QfZllIaSkYOc@6hHSpsJHWitgcokgwLDOw@6QuzglMoP)

My first Haskell golf, so it's probably not good lol

Comment: You can make `r` an infix function.  And you can define `g` with the arguements reversed (`g a n`) and then just do `g 1` as your anonymous function.

Comment: Here's your same approach more aggressively golfed down to [63 bytes](https://tio.run/##LcoxDoAgEATAr1xBiUYKO/AjxmITz0AANXDRxr@jhd0U41Ejp9Ta5mY8sN1s@n7R@VgJZIZp0ImFxBXGqgpfXCqr6o9bQWOSP4o1S8sIOzk6S9iFFAki0/hhay8 "Haskell – Try It Online")

Comment: @WheatWizard damn, that's nice, feels like that should be its own solution TBH but if you're okay with it I'll add it and my original into this answer

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal 3](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-3), 10 bytes

```
ЧṚ∦Ḋ≠gnt×Ẇ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.github.io/latest.html#WyIiLCIiLCLQp+G5muKIpuG4iuKJoGdudMOX4bqGIiwiIiwiMiIsIjMuNC4yIl0=)

Does not check the factors of anything, probably will be golfable

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-2), 65 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 8.125 bytes

```
λKṫṘcnt*;ṅ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2&c=1#WyI9QiIsIiIsIs67S+G5q+G5mGNudCo74bmFIiwiIiwiMiJd)

Bitstring:

```
00000010010010001000001010000111001101101101011011101111111011011
```

Slow method checking factors, but I had to beat Jelly.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 28 bytes

```
ＮθＷ‹ⅉθ«≦⊕φ¿∧﹪φχ∧⁻φ⮌φ¬﹪φ⮌φ⟦Ｉφ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY09D4IwFEVn@BVvfE0wwcTNiTiRCDFuxjhUeJUmpYV@4GD87bU4ccdz78ntBm47w1WMtZ6Cb8P4JIszO@bvQSoCPJNzeENWwMwYfPKs4VPlnHxprHVnaSTtqS9AJCWTArDSPTamD8qgKGBfJvOPpA5uJVdayDpCwVLTGr8Zb6o1cLFSe7yfuPOJPdLDN8ZD3C3qBw) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｎθ
```

Input `x`.

```
Ｗ‹ⅉθ«
```

Repeat until `x` terms have been output.

```
≦⊕φ
```

Increment the variable `f` which is predefined to `1000`.

```
¿∧﹪φχ∧⁻φ⮌φ¬﹪φ⮌φ
```

Check whether `f` is not a multiple of `10` or a palindrome but is divisible by its reverse.

```
⟦Ｉφ
```

Output it on its own line if this is the case.

52 bytes for a fast version:

```
ＮθＦＥθ⍘⊕ι²Ｆ²⊞υ⁺ι✂⮌ικＦ01ＵＭυ⪫Ｅ⪪κι⁺μ⌊μιＩ…▷SΣＥ89××⁹⁹ＩιＩυθ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://tio.run/##TY09D4IwFEVn@BVvfE0wwcTNiTiRCDFuxjhUeJUmpYV@4GD87bU4ccdz78ntBm47w1WMtZ6Cb8P4JIszO@bvQSoCPJNzeENWwMwYfPKs4VPlnHxprHVnaSTtqS9AJCWTArDSPTamD8qgKGBfJvOPpA5uJVdayDpCwVLTGr8Zb6o1cLFSe7yfuPOJPdLDN8ZD3C3qBw) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｎθ
```

Input `x`.

```
ＦＥθ⍘⊕ι²
```

Generate the binary numbers from `1` to `x`.

```
Ｆ²⊞υ⁺ι✂⮌ικ
```

Produce `2x` binary palindromes.

```
Ｆ01ＵＭυ⪫Ｅ⪪κι⁺μ⌊μι
```

Increase the run lengths of all of the runs by `1`.

```
Ｉ…▷SΣＥ89××⁹⁹ＩιＩυθ
```

Multiply each palindrome by both `792` and `891`, sort them into order, and output only the first `x`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 111 bytes

```
.+
*¶

$>:&*1
+`(1+)\1
${1}0
01
1
mL$w`^(.*)(?=.?$)
$%=$^$&
(.)\1*
$&$1
L$`.+
$.(792**)¶$.(891**
"$&,A`.+"^~)N`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DYwxCsJAFAX7d4zwXP7@lSVfBBMhBvvgCWRZCwsLLUSwED1WDpCLrdsNzDDP6@v2uFgpMUCXGeBh79QQsljwZwM/9m3RGgz3ie@cJKqXcYgjPbgamOggsaYKOhom5vpilF2/UfXLXLHrTRUN3fpYZZN@/pRL2XZ/) Explanation: In theory I could do this using unary division, but it would probably time out before producing any results at all, so I used the fact that all palintiples are either `792` or `891` times a palindromic string of `1`s and `0`s where no digit has a run length of `1`.

```
.+
*¶

$>:&*1
```

Generate the integers from `1` to `x+1` in unary.

```
+`(1+)\1
${1}0
01
1
```

Convert them to binary.

```
mL$w`^(.*)(?=.?$)
$%=$^$&
```

Produce `2x+2` binary palindromes.

```
(.)\1*
$&$1
```

Increase the run length of all the runs by `1`.

```
L$`.+
$.(792**)¶$.(891**
```

Multiply each palindrome by both `792` and `891`.

```
N`
```

Sort them in numeric order.

```
"$&,A`.+"^~)`
```

Keep only the first `x`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 40 bytes

```perl
$_%($;=reverse)|/^$;$|0$/||say while++$_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9r1Jja2j9XyVeVUPF2rYotSy1qDhVs0Y/TsVapcZARb@mpjixUqE8IzMnVVtbJf7//3/5BSWZ@XnF/3V9TfUMDA0A)

Outputs the sequence indefinitely.

Answer (score 1):

## [Raku (Perl 6) (rakudo)](https://raku.org), 48 bytes

```perl
(1..*).grep({$_%10&&$_!=.flip&&$_%%.flip})».say
```

(Continues indefinitely, printing out all the palintiples it finds.)

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kKDG7dMGCpaUlaboWNw00DPX0tDT10otSCzSqVeJVDQ3U1FTiFW310nIyC0BMVVUws1bz0G694sRKiD6odpgxAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Uiua 0.10.0](https://www.uiua.org/), <strike>32</strike> 30 bytes <sup>[SBCS](https://tinyurl.com/Uiua-SBCS-Mar-9)</sup>

```
⍥(+1⟨◌|&p⟩↧±◿10,>⊃◿≠⍜°⋕⇌...)∞0
```

[Try on Uiua Pad!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_10_0-dev_1__RiDihpAg4o2lKCsx4p-o4peMfCZw4p-p4oanwrHil78xMCw-4oqD4pe_4omg4o2cwrDii5Xih4wuLi4p4oieMAoKMCAjIHN0YXJ0aW5nIGF0IDAK4o2lKAogICMgcmVwZWF0CiAgLi4uICAgICMgZHVwIGlucHV0IDMgdGltZXMgb24gc3RhY2sKICDijZzCsOKLleKHjCAgICMgc3RyaW5naWZ5LCByZXZlcnNlLCB0aGVuIHBhcnNlCiAgPuKKg-KXv-KJoCAgICMgbSA9IDAgbW9kIG4gQU5EIG0gIT0gbgogIMKx4pe_MTAsICAjIHRlc3QgMTAgZG9lcyBub3QgZGl2aWRlIG0KICDihqcgICAgICAjIEFORCByZXN1bHRzCiAg4p-o4peMfCZw4p-pICMgcHJpbnQgaWYgdHJ1ZQogICsxICAgICAjIGFkZCAxIHRvIG0KKeKIniAgICAgICAjIHVudGlsIGZpeGVkIHBvaW50IChuZXZlcikK)

Prints indefinitely.

```
0        # starting at 0
⍥(       # repeat
  ...    # dup input 3 times on stack
  ⍜°⋕⇌   # stringify, reverse, then parse
  >⊃◿≠   # m = 0 mod n AND m != n
  ±◿10,  # test 10 does not divide m
  ↧      # AND results
  ⟨◌|&p⟩ # print if true
  +1     # add 1 to m
)∞       # until fixed point (never)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Scala 3](https://www.scala-lang.org/), 84 bytes

```scala
var m=9;while(1<2){m+=1;val r=m.toString.reverse.toInt;if(m==4*r||m==9*r)println(m)}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LYyxDoIwGIR3nuIfW4wkqIkCdnB0cFIn41CxYE1bzE_FGOBJXFjwnXgbm-D03V3u7vMtU674vBuWxeUuUgs7Lg3UHsBVZKCdIRzzMoYNIn-f9halyc80hqORFhjU_dNm09VwqDiCZlHyukklSLie0VpPWJhUXAEyHdhi3AYoKoGlcMHW2ERmRDO28LFpHCMf6cO1rDJE03b87gFa76-7buQP)

Answer (score 1):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_10_0-dev_1__4o2lKCsx4o2l4p-cJnDiiIo6w5c0XznijZzCsOKLleKHjC4uKeKInjEK), 23 bytes <sup>[SBCS](https://tinyurl.com/Uiua-SBCS-Mar-9)</sup>

[Try on Uiua Pad!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_10_0-dev_1__4o2lKCsx4o2l4p-cJnDiiIo6w5c0XznijZzCsOKLleKHjC4uKeKInjEK)

Prints indefinitely.

```
⍥(+1⍥⟜&p∊:×4_9⍜°⋕⇌..)∞1
```

Explain:

```
              ⍜°⋕⇌.     # generate palindrome from input
        ∊:×4_9     .    # if the 4*palindrome or 9*palindrome
    ⍥⟜&p                # print if true
  +1                    # increment
⍥(                  )∞1 # repeat forever, starting at 1
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
µNÑ¨íNåD–
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##ARsA5P9vc2FiaWX//8K1TsORwqjDrU7DpUTigJP//zQ)

**Explanation:**

```python
µ         # Loop while the counter variable (default 0) is not equal to the (implicit)
          # input-integer:
 N        #  Push the current loop-index
  Ñ       #  Pop and push a list of its divisors
   ¨      #  Remove the number itself (for palindrome cases)
    í     #  Reverse each divisor in the list
     Nå   #  Pop and check if the loop-index itself is in the list of reversed divisors
       D  #  Duplicate this check
        – #  Pop, and if it's truthy: print the loop-index with trailing newline
          #  Pop, and if it's truthy: implicitly increase the counter variable by 1
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Racket](https://racket-lang.org/), 223 bytes

```lisp
(define(r n a)(if(= n 0)a(r(quotient n 10)(+(* a 10)(modulo n 10)))))
(define(f x #:a[a 1])(if(= x 0)'()(if(and(>(modulo a 10)0)(not(=(r a 0)(r(r a 0)0)))(=(modulo a(r a 0))0))(cons a(f(- x 1)#:a(+ a 1)))(f x #:a(+ a 1)))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY/BDoIwDIbvPkUTDnYSIxy8mOiLGA8VNrOIm46R4NPjvwHu1H5rvz8N0jx1nIpO3INCbg536fXErTbWaQ7kSBRbw2dUlRIO/Bl8tNpFgLpSXPKOJFcv3w6dn3F6m9ViaKTiJFeM3RbZCNmWcyOu5cu6nE1wOR/5jHjBHDLnImlB19GFJsyNdz2I4T3UtUIal0mWNpb4P1AK99n@3cmX8HlE/wM)

Disclaimer: I'm not exactly good at golfing in Racket.

Answer (score 0):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), 82 bytes

```powershell
for(){if((++$i%10)*($i-ne($u=-join("$i"|% t*y|%{"$i"[-++$t]})))*!($i%$u)){$i}$t=0}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcpBCoAgEADAr1SssKsI9oBeEp1CaSMyzIhQ3251HJjD3zaci902Pftga3U@ICV2iEoBi96QRGC9W4Rr0KvnHTvgLosmyieL9GPU341TISLZflvARZSAC8TBlFpf)

Prints all the palintiple, separated by newlines